# Getting the current time in specified timezone

Tags: rust, rust-chrono, chrono-tz

Using the [Chrono-TZ library](https://github.com/djzin/chrono-tz), how can I get the current time in a specified time zone?

I tried

```
let naive_dt = Local::now().naive_local();
let dt = Los_Angeles.from_local_datetime(&naive_dt).unwrap();
println!("{:#?}", dt);
```

But this printed the datetime in my current timezone, and affixed the requested timezone identifier, thereby giving me a datetime that is off by the difference in timezones.

For example, at 18:30 AEST (UTC+10), I ask for the current time in PST (UTC-8). It should be 00:30 PST. Instead I get 18:30 PST

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Construct the value based on UTC, not local times.

```
let utc = UTC::now().naive_utc();
let dt = Los_Angeles.from_utc_datetime(&utc);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`chrono::DateTime::with_timezone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.with_timezone) to convert a `DateTime<Utc>` to another time zone.

Example:

```rust
#![forbid(unsafe_code)]
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use chrono_tz::Tz;
use chrono_tz::US::Pacific;

fn main() {
    let pacific_now: DateTime<Tz> = Utc::now().with_timezone(&Pacific);
    println!("pacific_now = {}", pacific_now);
}
```

```
$ cargo run --bin example
pacific_now = 2021-07-01 23:22:11.052490 PDT
```